# API calling in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Assume that there are 3 APIs. Each API does exactly the same task(to give you weather details) but has different endpoints as follows:

API 1: Can only be used for India. Has methods named `requestWeather(), requestWeatherDataForWeek()`

API 2: Can only be used for the USA. Has methods named `sendRequest(), weatherDataForWeek()`

API 3: Can only be used for the UK. Has methods named `getWeather(), getWeatherDataForWeek()`.

Select the country using the drop-down.

a. Select the API according to the country. API selection is programmatic, which will be decided according to the country selected by the user.

b. Write your code such that, any API can be used without disturbing the business logic.

c. There must be a limit on the number of requests that can be sent. Throw an error if no. of requests exceed the limit.

d. It does not require HTTP calls or APIs. Just create a wrapper for API with the specified method and return some dummy values.

```
weatherApp.config(function ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {



    $stateProvider

      .state('/', {
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'homeController'
      })

      .state('forecast', {
        url:"/forecast",
        templateUrl: 'forecast.html',
        controller: 'forecastController'
      })
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
    });
    weatherApp.service('cityService', function() {

      this.city = "New York, NY";

    });
    weatherApp.controller('Controller',['$scope','$state',function($scope,$state){
      $scope.clicked=function(){
        $state.go('forecast');
      };
    }]);

    weatherApp.controller('homeController', ['$scope', 'cityService', function($scope, cityService) {

      $scope.city = cityService.city;

      $scope.$watch('city', function() {
       cityService.city = $scope.city; 
     });

    }]);
    weatherApp.controller('forecastController', ['$scope', '$resource', '$routeParams', 'cityService', function($scope, $resource, $routeParams, cityService) {
      $scope.city = cityService.city;

      $scope.days = $routeParams.days || 2;
      $scope.weatherAPI = $resource("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily", { callback: "JSON_CALLBACK" }, { get: { method: "JSONP" }});

      $scope.weatherResult = $scope.weatherAPI.get({ q: $scope.city, cnt: $scope.days });

      $scope.convertToFahrenheit = function(degK) {

        return Math.round((1.8 * (degK - 273)) + 32);

      }
      $scope.convertToDate = function(dt) { 

        return new Date(dt * 1000);
      };
    }]);
```

I tried in this way. How do we create a wrapper and not include HTTP and APIs?

Comment: See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: @georgeawg Understood. Thank you.

Comment: @georgeawg Tried it using HTTP and APIs.